# after effects 2023 (latest) and deadline

Tags: after-effects, render

Testing a move to AWS Thinkbox Deadline (10.1.23nnn) for the VFX studio I work at.  Just rolled updates to Adobe After Effects, which moves the version to 2023--causing all manner of references to "23" to fail on my tests.  Is there a straightforward way to "line up" these versions?

Thanks,
PGE